# error "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: collection' "" ASP:NET MVC C# Visual Studio 2017 dataTables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, datatables

I have a dataTable in which I have a view to edit the data.

It works but not when I add in my model some Requirements like:

```
    public class ModelTemplateEmail
{      
    [Display(Name = "EmailId")]
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "UserName")][StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Do not enter more than 20 characters")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a User name")]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$", ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid.")] 
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Title")]      
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }    
    public List<ModelTemplateEmail> EmailDataList { get; set; }     

    [Key]
    public int languageID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Language")]
    public string MainLanguage { get; set; }

}
```

I get an error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: collection'

when debugging in my view in one dropDown list Which is not de data I put the requirements so I don't understand why is this error and how to solve it.

The string that have the error is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.languageID, new List<SelectListItem>(ViewBag.MainLanguage), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The controller of my DropDwnList is:

```
public void MainLanguagelist()
    {
        var sqlstring = string.Format("SELECT [languageID], [MainLanguage] FROM [dbo].[Language]");

        var myConnection = getconection();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConnection);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter Language = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataSet setLanguageData = new DataSet();
        Language.Fill(setLanguageData);
        ViewBag.MainLanguageList = setLanguageData.Tables[0];
        List<SelectListItem> MainLanguageList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (DataRow MainLanguage in ViewBag.MainLanguageList.Rows)
        {
           MainLanguageList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = @MainLanguage["MainLanguage"].ToString(),
           Value = @MainLanguage["languageID"].ToString()});
        }

        ViewBag.MainLanguage = MainLanguageList;


        try
        {             
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Action result:

```
    public ActionResult EditData(int EmailId, string userName, string Title, string Email, string description, int languageID)
    {

            ModelTemplateEmail Editdata = new ModelTemplateEmail
            {
              EmailId = EmailId, userName = userName, Email = Email, description = description,
              Title = Title, languageID = languageID
            };

             MainLanguagelist();

        return View(Editdata);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditData(ModelTemplateEmail modelEmail)
    {
        UpdateDataBase(modelEmail.EmailId, modelEmail.userName, modelEmail.Title, 
                       modelEmail.Email,modelEmail.description, modelEmail.languageID);


        return View ();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the ViewBag.MainLanguage value is null. Make sure you set it on the controller before returning the view.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it adding `MainLanguagelist();` in my http post method.